# Store text and variable in a cell and assign it to variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am storing Text and Variable in a cell 
e.g.   Cell A1 contains "Current Month: " &   p_Month

```
Mail_Subject = WS.Range("A1").value
```

but `MsgBox (Mail_Subject)` shows **"Current Month: " &   p_Month**

instead **Current Month: February**

How can I get the variable interpreted ?

Comment: p_Month would have to be a named range to work in that way (if your actual cell says that) and that named range would need to contain "February"

Comment: I feel like there has to be a better way. Why does it need to be the variable name? How is the rest of this structured/functioning?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my example: p_month is a VBA variable I use in the code. e.g. p_month is a variable from a dropdown value if a form

Answer (score 0):

p_Month would have to be a [named range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) to work in that way (if your actual cell says that) and that named range would need to contain "February"

so create a named range called p_Month using Name Manager. Then in that named range (single cell will do) put the text "January".

Then in A1 put

```
="Current Month: " & p_Month
```

**Example named range** (see name box top left)

[image: Named Range]

**Testing code** (Change sheet name as appropriate):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Testing()

Dim Mail_Subject As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Mail_Subject = ws.Range("A1").Value

MsgBox Mail_Subject

End Sub
```